# Reset Variables After InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, interrupt

I have a program with multiple threads operating on a single instance of a class. Sometimes one of these threads will get interrupted. I have in the method header "throws InterruptedException" so it does that part correctly. The problem is that when a thread gets interrupted, the fields don't get reset, so the next thread that comes in gets all messed up.

How do I check if a thread is interrupted so that I can reset the variables for the next thread that comes in? I'm not sure where to address this in my code. I have tried something like:

```
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    //reset variables here
}
```

or:

```
if(Thread.interrupted()) {
    //reset variables here
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can encase your whole thing in a try-catch block:

```java
try {
    //Code here
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Reset variables here
}
```

Comment: The problem is, if I do that it no longer throws the exception. It catches it instead. Is that correct? I am doing this for an assignment so I need it to throw the exception as well.

Comment: Oh nevermind I figured it out. I just add the "throw new InterruptedException();! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check (or handle) if a thread has been interrupted in two ways:

1. You receive an InterruptedException when performing operations that might keep your thread waiting for an undefined amount of time, like a sleep or a wait invocation.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   public void run(){
      try {
         while(true){
            someOperation();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
         }
      } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
         //reset variables
      }
   }
}
```

2. If you're performing some heavy operations, you might wanna check in specific points of your code if you've received an interruption with the methods you mentioned above.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   public void run(){
      while(true){
         someHeavyOperation();
         if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            //reset variables
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's also a link to the Oracle Tutorials explaining Java's support to thread interruption

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: I am trying to do the second option, but my code never enters into that "if" statement. Where in my code should I be putting it?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Thank you for the help!